# Heat Equation Existence of Fourier Series

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

I'm currently doing a bit of digging with the Heat Equation and the Fourier Series.

It seems that the boundary condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$ can be arbitrary. At some point, we get something like (in a greatly simplified manner) $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}B_n \sin \left ( knx \right )$ for some constant $k$.

Since $f(x)$ is any arbitrary function, does this mean that we've essentially 'proven' that any (non-pathological I guess) function $f(x)$ can be expressed in the form $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}B_n \sin \left ( knx \right )$?

Or is this moreso a 'demonstration' or 'motivation' to believe that it is possible that any function can be expressed as the infinite sum of sines and cosines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joseph Fourier claimed this in 1822 here:

- [Théorie analytique de la chaleur (The analytic theory of heat)](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k1045508v/f294.image.r=fourier.langEN)

> Il résulte de tout ce qui a été démontré dans cette section,
>   concernant le développement des fonctions en séries trigonométriques,
>   que si l'on propose une fonction $f x$, dont la valeur est répresenté
>   dans un intervalle déterminé, depuis $x=0$ jusqu'à $x=X$, par l'ordonné
>   d'une ligne courbe tracée arbitrairement on pourra toujours développer
>   cette fonction en un série qui ne contiendra que les sinus, ou les cosinus,
>   ou les sinus et cosinus des arcs multiples, ou les seuls cosinus des
>   multiples impairs. On ne peut résoudre entièrement les questions
>   fondamentales de la théorie de la chaleur, sans réduire à cette forme
>   les fonctions qui représentent l'état initial des températures.
>
> (It follows from what has been shown in this section, concerning the
>   development of functions in trigonometric series, if one offers a
>   function $f x$, whose value is represented in a given interval from $x = 0$
>   to $x = X$, ordered by a curved line drawn arbitrarily we can always
>   expand this function in a series that will contain only sine or cosine
>   or sine and cosine multiple arcs or cosine only odd multiples . One
>   can not fully solve the fundamental problems of the theory of heat,
>   without reducing to this form the functions that represent the initial 
>   state of temperature.)

(part 235., page 258)

Answer (score 0):

It's implicit in the proof that the series converges in the appropriate sense to $f$; here we require, by the way, that $f$ be defined on some appropriate finite interval $[a, b]$ (we might also allow cosine terms depending on the formulation). Here, the appropriate notion of nonpathological at least requires that we can integrate $f$ against the functions $\sin(knx)$; more precisely, we demand that $f \in L^2([a, b])$; this is also the appropriate space for convergence to a function of its Fourier series. It's not surprising that $L^2$ is a good setting for this problem: The coefficients of the series are given by integrals, which themselves don't see the difference between two functions which differ on a set of measure zero.